# Higchahrts click entire column to trigger point click event

Tags: highcharts

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sxm38nsj/4/

When the xAxis is a string, I can get the index of click point.

But when the xAxis is datetime, how can I get the index? Or how can I trigger the point's click events? 
eg:http://jsfiddle.net/sxm38nsj/5/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
          click:function(e){
            var column = Math.abs(Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value));
            alert('bland:',column);
            this.series[0].data[column].firePointEvent('click', event);
          }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            //pointPadding: 0.2,
            //borderWidth: 0
            point:{
                events:{
                click: function(){
                    alert(this.x);
                    console.log(this);
                }
              }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
        }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in method `series.searchPoint()` to find closest point to the mouse (or rather event) position, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/sxm38nsj/6/

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    click: function(e) {
      var chart = this;

      point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(chart.pointer.normalize(e));
      if (point) {
        point.firePointEvent('click', event);
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Another solution** is to find closest point to your `column` value. You can search `series.xData` array, to get index of the closest point to the mouse event.